# How to continue playing videos when i close an HTML tab?

Tags: javascript, html, video, tabs

How can I do to continue playing a video when the user close the tab? Is there any possible way?

For example, YouTube.

I thought that perhaps before closing the tab I could store the current position and continue playing from there, but I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way could be to store their position in the video every 5 seconds or so? I'm not sure how expensive that could become on the back end though.